# Some logic within Lambda function is not being executed in all invocations

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, axios

Code involving an http request to an external weather API is not being executed on all function invocations and not just on cold starts either.

Heres a snippet of part of the code with the relevant logic:

```
let weatherReport = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json',
      params: {
        key: weatherApiKey,
        q: city,
        days: 1,
      },
    });

    let dailyForecast = await weatherReport.data.forecast.forecastday[0]
      .day;

    let dailyChanceOfRain = Number(dailyForecast.daily_chance_of_rain);
    let totalPrecip = dailyForecast.totalprecip_mm;
    
    console.log(dailyForecast);
    console.log('dailyChanceOfRain: ', dailyChanceOfRain);
    console.log('totalPrecip: ', totalPrecip);
```

In some invocations, I don't get any logs relating to the http request and in others, I do for some reason. However, I need access to the response of the request on every invocation so the function won't work correctly without a consistent result on every invocation.

Any advice would be much appreciated, this has bugged me for days.

Comment: By no logs, you mean that there is nothing in CW Logs regarding your function?

Comment: @Marcin yes nothing in cloudWatch on some invocations then they appear on other invocations. Also, they never appear on a cold start.

Comment: Maybe function gets throttled?

Comment: @Marcin I can't see any indication that the function is being throttled in CloudWatch, so not sure whether that's it. Is there a way of identifying whether this is happening other than in cloudWatch?

Comment: Are you saying that the START/END logs aren't appearing in CW Logs (which suggests you're not being invoked at all) or just your console.logs? Any chance they are being logged, but you're looking in the wrong log stream (they could be appended to a previous log stream)?

Comment: I wonder if it is timing-out? Please edit your question to show the log for a 'failed' execution. It should show information about how long the function executed.